# Count number of span id by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a PHP page I have a list of results.
I want to get the number of results by date in order to display a pie chart.

It's what i have:

```
<span id="tweetdate_1_12-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_12-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_3_12-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_4_12-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_1_11-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_11-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_1_10-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_10-11-2012">...</span>
```

I want to get in javascript :
 1. The dates like this: 10-11-2012, 11-11-2012, 12-11-2012
 2. The number of results by dates: 2, 2, 4

I have recovered the dates but not in the good order (olded first) and not the number of theses dates.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery code, and will get an Object with date as key.

```
$(function(){
 var ret = {};
  $('span[id^="tweetdate"]').each(function(){
      var tmp_array = this.id.split('_');
      var date = tmp_array[tmp_array.length-1];
      if(ret[date]){
          ret[date] ++;
      }else{
          ret[date] = 1;
     }
  });
  console.log(ret);
});
```

The result seems in order. Or if you are not sure, you can sort it before using.

Comment: I have done it with only PHP but this solution is very good :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in this manner,

***jquery code***

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   count = 0;
   $('span').each(function(){
     if($(this).attr('id').match(/12-11-2012/)) {
          count++;
     }
  });
  $('#count').html(count);
}); 
</script>
```

***html code***

```
<span id="tweetdate_1_12-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_12-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_3_12-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_4_12-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_1_11-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_11-11-2012">...</span>
<span id="tweetdate_1_10-11-2012">...</span> 
<span id="tweetdate_2_10-11-2012">...</span>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more succinct:

```
var count = $('span[id*=12-11-2012]').length;
$('#count').html(count);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: `$("span[id^=tweetdate_][id$=12-11-2012]").length` perhaps?